# How to save an array of strings into a PFObject for iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, string, parse-platform, pfobject

I want to create (or update) a PFObject with an array of strings, so that each element of the array can be editable. For example, I want the array to contain the words "Hello" and "World" so that if I wanted, I could access and rewrite the first element of the array to instead say "Goodbye".

Here's what I have:

```
PFObject *newStringArray = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"myFirstClass"];
[newStringArray setObject:@"Hello" forKey:@"arrayOfStrings"];
[newStringArray saveInBackground];
```

The above code doesn't give me any errors, and it doesn't save to Parse. I've also tried using:

```
[newStringArray addObjectsFromArray:@[@"Hello", @"World"] forKey:@"arrayOfStrings"];
```

But this code returns the error "Error: invalid type for key arrayOfStrings, expected string, but got array"

Please let me know if you have any suggestions for how I can fix the array problem, or if I should be trying a different method of collecting/accessing strings within a wall of text. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only save in Parse if the column `arrayOfStrings` in your class `myFirstClass` actually expects an array. In that case the code would look something like this:

```
[newStringArray setObject:@[@"Hello", @"World"] forKey:@"arrayOfStrings"];
```

But your class `myFirstClass` obviously expects a string as the error message is telling you. So you will have change that in Parse itself.

Also always check the correct spelling for the classes and keys. They are case sensitive.

By the way, `addObjectsFromArray:` only does what it says. It will add the objects from that array to the one already set for that key. If there is no array set it will not work.